# How to install Nextcloud (with a compatible version of PHP) on an RasPi 3B+ running Arch linux (arm)?

Tags: software-installation, archlinux, software-compilation, software-compatibility, nextcloud

- I want to install Nextcloud on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ running Arch Linux.
- Nextcloud requires a version of PHP: `7.1 <= x < 7.4.0`.
- I have done a lot of research, and there seems to be no place on the entire internet which offers a PHP version of `7.1`, `7.2` nor the version `7.3`.

Not that I would want to use `7.1` anyways, since it's no longer supported.

But apparently, the people behind the Arch ARM repositories have decided, that it would be a good idea to **NOT** offer older versions of packages (at least for the ARM architecture).

This leads to my browser only showing me the error page of the Nextcloud version-check:

> This version of Nextcloud is not compatible with > PHP 7.3.
>   You are currently running 7.4.1.

---

As it turns out, the 18 lines of PHP code in this file prohibit unsupported versions of PHP from running Nextcloud: `/usr/share/webapps/nextcloud/lib/versioncheck.php`

However, circumventing the version check as was proposed as a "quick fix" [**here**](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/this-version-of-nextcloud-is-not-compatible-with-php-7-3/65332) has turned out to be pointless. However, I got a nice background behind a new error, for the duration I kept the changes in the version check.

### Summary

This leads me to ask my question:

What is the best (or recommended) approach for installing a compatible version of PHP on my Raspberry Pi?

I think I might have to compile an older version from source myself.
I consider this to be a good option, assuming I can build for ARM on my 64bit CPU of my PC, as the compilation time on the Raspberry Pi would likely take very long.

And after I compiled the code: How would I make an installable package and install it?

Thanks in advance.

---

Please be advised, that there are other (not directly Pi-related) questions for the topic of cross-compiling PHP, such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559480/cross-compiling-php/25708463

Comment: This is really a question about how to downgrade a package in Arch linux and should be researched as such.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Barch-linux%5D+downgrade

Comment: @goldilocks Thanks for your quick response. I already have researched the topic as such extensively and as it turns out, there are no older packages available for download, leading me to ask how to cross-compile PHP for the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I'm not an arch user but a quick search for "arch downgrade php" turned up this: https://www.linode.com/community/questions/18896/downgrade-php-73-on-arch-linux ...Which may be a tidier option.  While it does mean compiling on the Pi, I would think twice about cross-compiling php if this post represents where you are with that.